# Oscillation of an object suspended on an unstretched horizontal elastic string

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

The physics concepts here are: small oscillations around equilibrium, elastic strings.

Let me show you my approach to the following problem. But first the problem description from the problem book.

*Unstretched elastic string is suspended horizontally. Its stiffness is $k=16N/m$. At the centre of the string, a weight of mass $m=0.024kg$ is attached and then lightly pulled downwards. Find the period of small oscillations, given that angle between horizontal and the string is small.*

[image]

Before the weight is pulled downward, let $\alpha$ be the angle from the string to the horizontal and x the total elongation of the string. From force equilibrium I got: $mg=2kx\cdot sin(\alpha)$.

After the motion has begun, I got: $ma=mg-2kX\cdot sin(\beta)$ (positive downwards). Where $X$ is the new total elongation of the string and $\beta$ is the new angle.

Let $L$ be the unstretched length of the string. This allows to write two equations:

$sin(\alpha)=\frac{2y}{\sqrt{4y^2+L^2}}$ and
$sin(\beta)=\frac{2Y}{\sqrt{4Y^2+L^2}}$

Where $y$ is the distance by which weight drops from the horizontal line in the equilibrium. Furthermore, $Y$ is the distance from the horizontal line during oscillation.

One can also say that: $y^2+\frac{L^2}{4}=\frac{(L+x)^2}{4}$ and $Y^2+\frac{L^2}{4}=\frac{(L+X)^2}{4}$

I then got rid of $x, X, sin(\alpha)$ and $sin(\beta)$ from first two equations.

Combining these two gives:

$ma=4k\cdot[y-Y+L(\frac{Y}{\sqrt{4Y^2+L^2}}-\frac{y}{\sqrt{4y^2+L^2}})]$

The $4k\cdot (y-Y)$ part looks good! Some signs of SHM equation appear!

Linearization around $Y-y=0$ gives:

$ma=4k(y-Y)\cdot[1-\frac{L^3}{\sqrt{4y^2+L^2}^3}]$

Well, I showed that ma is proportional to $(y-Y)$ or $(Y-y)$. But this doesn't give me the answer from the author (given only using $m$ and $k$...). Which I give below. Can you help me with identifying what went wrong? Or maybe should I use a different approach?

I couldn't find similar problems elsewhere, I only found a Polish forum thread from 15 years ago when some physicists tried to solved it with no success.

[image: Answer]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I got this solution :

the kinetic energy is

$$T=\frac 12\,m\,v^2\quad,
 v=\dot y=\frac L2\frac{d}{dt}\,\tan(\alpha)$$

the potential energy is:

$$U=m\,g\,y+k\,s_l^2=m\,g\,\frac L2\,\tan(\alpha)+
k\,s_l^2$$

where $~s_l~$  is the "spring length"

$$s_l^2=\left(\frac L2\right)^2+y^2= 
\left(\frac L2\right)^2+\left(\frac L2\,\tan(\alpha)\right)^2$$

from here with EL the equation of motion

$$\ddot\alpha+f(\alpha~,~\dot\alpha)=0\tag 1$$

linearized Eq.1 $~\alpha \ll~$

$$\ddot\alpha+2\,{\frac {g}{L}}+2\,{\frac {k\alpha}{m}}+2\,\alpha\,{\dot\alpha }^{2}
=0$$

thus $~\omega^2=\frac {2\,k}{m}~$

Comment: Taking the potential energy as $ks_l^2$ implies that the strings were stretched from a length of zero. This doesn't seem to represent the problem accurately.

Comment: I know, but this doesn’t change the result.

Answer (score -1):

Use symmetry to consider only half the problem: a mass $\frac{m}{2}$ constrained to move vertically (with slight deflection $y$ measured downward), suspended from a nearly horizontal string of length $L$ and at slight downward angle $\theta$ (thus, $\frac{y}{L}=\tan\theta\approx\theta$).

The stretching of the string is

$$\Delta L=\sqrt{L^2+y^2}-L\approx \frac{y^2}{2L},$$

and so the axial string force is

$$k\Delta L=\frac{ky^2}{2L}$$

with upward component multiplied by $\sin\theta$, or

$$\frac{ky^2}{2L}\sin\theta\approx \frac{ky^2\theta}{2L}\approx \frac{ky^3}{2L^2}.$$

Linearized for small displacements around position $y_0$, this is

$$\frac{ky^3}{2L^2}\approx \frac{ky_0^3}{2L^2}+3\frac{ky_0^2}{2L^2}y,$$

so the equation of motion, summing upward and downward forces, is

$$\frac{m}{2}\ddot y=-\frac{ky_0^3}{2L^2}-\frac{3ky_0^2}{2L^2}y+\frac{mg}{2}.$$

But the equilibrium position $y_0$ is where the weight counteracts the string tension at rest, or

$$\frac{ky_0^3}{2L^2}=\frac{mg}{2},$$

so the linearized equation of motion is

$$\frac{m}{2}\ddot y=-\frac{3ky_0^2}{2L^2}y,$$

corresponding to a natural frequency of $\omega=\sqrt{\frac{3ky_0^2}{mL^2}}$ and a period of $$T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{mL^2}{3ky_0^2}}=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{y_0}{3g}}=2\pi\left(\frac{mL^2}{27kg^2}\right)^{1/6}.$$

I'm not seeing how to usefully simplify this further.